# Generating Email alert for events in system log

Tags: rhel, email, rsyslog

How to generate email alert for  every critical event logged in system log `/var/log/messages`.

Suppose, for the following log message, I want an email alert to be generated.

```
Oct 24 11:17:42 eforms ipmievd: Voltage sensor - Lower Critical going low
```

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/32360/how-can-i-make-syslogd-email-certain-log-messages-to-me ; http://askubuntu.com/questions/235868/how-can-i-monitor-syslog-and-send-notification-based-on-events